# Spring SpEL access Configuration-Bean

Tags: spring, spring-el

I am working in a legacy software where most of the configuration is externalized from `application.properties` it resides in a file called `custom.properties` which will be read into a configuration bean that is declared like that.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = "classpath:custom.properties", ignoreUnknownFields = true, prefix = "custom")
public class CustomProperties {
...
}
```

This application has some scheduled tasks, which where declared to work at a fixed interval and time. `@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 16 * * 3")` Until now everything works fine. Recently I have been asked to make this cronjob happen at a configurable time. So I added another property to `custom.properties` and an attribute to `CustomProperties` (including getter and setter). Next I altered the scheduled annotation to look like this. `@Scheduled(cron = "${@customProperties.cronJob1Schedule}")`

When I start the application I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'cronJob1': Could not resolve placeholder '@customProperties.cronJob1Schedule' in string value "${@bwvProperties.cronJob1Schedule}"
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.processScheduled(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:406)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
```

Has anybody had that issue before? Why cant I access the configuration bean in SpEL?

Comment: Is this a typo `@customProperties.cronJob1Schedule` ? Shouldn't it be `${customProperties.cronJob1Schedule}` ?

Comment: This is not SPeL. SPeL starts with hash sign `#{your.spel}`. Dollar sign means simple property resolution `${your.property}` based on *property sources*.

Comment: @PavelHoral that was the hint i needed `#{@cumstomProperties.cronJob1Schedule}` worked. Make it an answer and I will upvote.

Comment: @Mr.H. Done. Tried to put some additional value into it as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Be careful that there are two distinct mechanisms that work on string values processed by Spring:

### Property resolution - `${my.property}`

Spring is able to replace placeholders `${placeholder}` with values from configured [*property sources*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html). This proces simply replaces string key with a string value (and runs it through a [converter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html) if needed).

### Spring Expression Language evaluation - `#{spel.expression}`

Spring is able to run contents of `#{}` through [SPeL](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) interpretter. This offers much more powerful tool as you can interact with your application code from inside your expression, e.g. by getting property from one of your bean `#{@cumstomProperties.cronJob1Schedule}`.

### TL;DR

You just need to switch `${` for `#{` in your annotation value.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you've made a typo, assuming you're injecting your config properties similar to this:

`@Autowired 
private CustomProperties bwvProperties`

It should be `#{bwvProperties.cronJob1Schedule}` - drop the `@`, change `$` by `#`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution would have worked but i did not want to inject CustomProperties because it is not referenced by any code the syntaxchecker would have recognized. So with your solution there might be the possibility that an unexperienced coworker deletes the autowired bean without recognizing that this would damage the application. `#{@cumstomProperties.cronJob1Schedule}` works without injecting the configuration.